# Window scroll bar performance issue

Tags: jquery

```
var box = $('.box');

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - 100;
    box.css('top', top);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ALFdL/

If I scroll down a little faster, the box will like shake a little bit, is there an option like fps to adjust the scroll down frequency, I want to box move after scroll down as fast as just like fixed there.

PS: I know I can use fixed for this case, but it's just a demo code to emulate the real case.

Comment: On every scroll, your `Scroll` function is running thats why its taking time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no necessity to use jQuery and try to fix some perormance issue when you can make this kind of box simply using CSS. Look for modified **[jsFiddly](http://jsfiddle.net/Antindexer/ALFdL/1/)**.

In change `position` property and add `z-index` CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/6/);
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index:100;
}
```

So, `position:fixed;` makes your box fixed to the given position. `z-index:100;` makes it on top of other pictures.

Comment: PS: I know I can use fixed for this case, but it's just a demo code to emulate the real case.

Answer (score 0):

No. Scroll speed is determined by the browser (and usually directly by the settings on the computer/device). CSS and Javascript don't (or shouldn't) have any way to affect system settings.

See here: [Can I change the scroll speed using css or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408100/can-i-change-the-scroll-speed-using-css-or-jquery)