# How to manipulate user scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, jquery-animate

I need to manipulate user scroll in next way:

[image: Scroll example]

When user in some `<section>` he can only scroll slowly, then if he will reach ~80% of the section, automatically scroll to the top of the next `<section>`

Detailed explanation:
I need to slow down the scroll inside an element (in my case it's `<section>`) and if the view of the `<section>` is scrolled more than 80% scroll to the top of the next section.

The main question is how to slow down the scroll. How to scroll to the next section after 80% of the current is less important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery to scroll up/down or scroll to an element.

you can say:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100)
{
    // do some thing 
}
```

I also calculate height percent like this:

```
var h = (($("#one").height())*80/100);
```

See jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/q36fLcaa/

Comment: Thank you for that, but how to slow down the scroll speed and make it smooth for browsers that immediately scrolls some amount of pixels (e.g. Chrome on Windows).

Comment: @Demid Ganenko I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408100/can-i-change-the-scroll-speed-using-css-or-jquery for slow down scroll speed
and jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/NFk2L/
 see that's work for you.

Comment: found it too. But after some search used it https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll