# how to reduce the scrolling value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I would like to adjust the scroll value of the mouse wheel.

I would like to manipulate 400px to 200px when the scrollTop value is 400px.

Is there a way?

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: Use nice scroll plugin. It's a nice plugin.

Comment: Here is one way: https://jsfiddle.net/xoL29gp6/1/ (Bad UX though - Please dont do it unless you absolutely have to)

Answer (score 0):

The scroll speed CAN be changed, adjusted, reversed, all of the above - via javascript (or a js library such as jQuery).

WHY would you want to do this? Parallax is just one of the reasons. I have no idea why anyone would argue against doing so -- the same negative arguments can be made against hiding DIVs, sliding elements up/down, etc. Websites are always a combination of technical functionality and UX design -- a good designer can use almost any technical capability to improve UX. That is what makes him/her good.

Toni Almeida of Portugal created a brilliant demo, reproduced below:
See Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/36dp03ur/

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">
    Use the mouse wheel (not the scroll bar) to scroll this DIV. You will see that the scroll eventually slows down, and then stops. <span class="boldit">Use the mouse wheel (not the scroll bar) to scroll this DIV. You will see that the scroll eventually slows down, and then stops. </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function wheel(event) {
  var delta = 0;
  if (event.wheelDelta) {(delta = event.wheelDelta / 120);}
  else if (event.detail) {(delta = -event.detail / 3);}

  handle(delta);
  if (event.preventDefault) {(event.preventDefault());}
  event.returnValue = false;
 }

function handle(delta) {
  var time = 1000;
  var distance = 300;

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
  }, time );
  }

  if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);}
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
```

Source : [Can I change the scroll speed using css or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408100/can-i-change-the-scroll-speed-using-css-or-jquery)