# Smooth scrolling using mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wonder what's the plugin/css trick behind this page to achieve the smooth scrolling - http://templates.framework-y.com/dark/ . As you can see when you scroll, the page continues to scroll after you stop scrolling with 3rd mouse button.

Comment: A smooth scroll script ..

Comment: A quick look in the source code and you would've found this: https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That kind of script is call : "Smooth Scroll". You can find examples in this stackoverflow's question : [Can I change the scroll speed using css or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408100/can-i-change-the-scroll-speed-using-css-or-jquery)

Here is an example and the github of the script :

http://simov.github.io/simplr-smoothscroll/examples/example-02.html
https://github.com/simov/simplr-smoothscroll