# Slowing down scroll speed while using trackpad

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, frontend

I am currently developing a website that has some animations on scroll. The problem is that animation is triggered too fast when the user is scrolling using a touchpad. My question is: Is it possible to slow down the scrolling speed on touchpad or at least determine if user uses a mouse wheel or trackpad?

Comment: Please never slow down someone's scrolling speed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change the scroll speed using css or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408100/can-i-change-the-scroll-speed-using-css-or-jquery)

Comment: Thank you for your response Nate, but unfortunately, it doesn't. I need to change scrolling speed only for touchpads as animation works fine for the mouse wheel.