# Change HTML document scroll rate

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am trying to get the HTML document to scroll slower. For example, this document scrolls at a constant rate determined by the browser:

```css
div{
  background-color:#00ffff;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:3600px;">Try scrolling this container. Try scrolling this container. Try scrolling this container. Try scrolling this container. Try scrolling this container.</div>
```

But I an trying to modify the scroll speed:

```js
document.onscroll = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.scrollBy(0,2);
}
```

```html
<div style="height:3600px;">scroll this container!</div>
```

But then, when the body is scrolling and the user **stops scrolling,** the content is still scrolling. Is there any problem with that code?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408100/can-i-change-the-scroll-speed-using-css-or-jquery